# How to impose ABS unto a range while taking the AVERAGEIF?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I'd like to take the AVERAGEIF of a range, more specifically calculate the average using the values in their absolute form.

Therefore I'd like to do a function such as: =AVERAGEIF(W13:W1553;"42018";ABS(O13:O1553))

But this won't work in Excel...

Can someone help? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

AVERAGEIF will not allow the manipulation of the ranges.  One would need to use an array formula:

```
=AVERAGE(IF((W13:W1553=42018)*(O13:O1553<>""));ABS(O13:O1553)))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

---

If one does not want to use an array formula, one can use a helper column to get the ABS of the number row.

In Z13 put `=ABS(O13)` then copy down to row 1553 and then use AVERAGEIF

```
=AVERAGEIF(W13:W1553;"42018";Z13:Z1553))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but the average it gives me in your formula isn't accurate... any tips as to how come this might be?

Comment: @user12405343 not without data.

Comment: The data range that I'd like to take the ABS from has blank cells. That is why the average isn't accurate. Do you know how I could modify your formula to ignore the blank cells in the ABS function? Thank you!

Comment: Does the * you added in the formula mean multiply? I am not sure I understand what the edit of your formula means, could you explain it? Thank you though!!

Comment: Yes, but in this case it is effectively `And` so it must equal `42018` AND not be empty.